# Devbridge AutoComplete with Ajax doesn't fill suggestions

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete

I have a autocomplete field which triggers a server search on fullname in a db with a JSON response.

It is working fine when I use a local array but when I use the JSON server response then the suggestion list is not updated even though the response seems correct in the Network console (to my knowledge).

I have no error in my console and it is not a CSS issue because when I inspect the code, the suggestion div is empty.

Here is my html input field:

```
<input type="text" id="form_fullname" name="form[fullname]" required="required" class="contact-select form-control" autocomplete="off" data-cip-id="form_fullname">
```

Here is the autocomplete-suggestions div:

```
<div class="autocomplete-suggestions" style="position: absolute; display: none; max-height: 300px; z-index: 9999;"></div>
```

Here is my js:

```
$('.contact-select').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: 'contacts/search/fullname/',
    minChars: 3,
    deferRequestBy: 200
})
```

And here is a JSON response (validated on JSONLint):

```
{"query":"vial-","suggestions":["VIAL-COLLET, Bastien"]}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ouch... I had my autocomplete method added in a ajaxComplete callback... no idea why !
It's now working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same autocomplete plugin, everything works fine except that the suggestion list does not update when the user type. The whole list just appears there.

Here is my JS code:

```
`$('#searchName').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: "getfoodname.php",
        minChars: 2,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                //alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
                window.open("/detail.php?MonAnID="+suggestion.data,"_self")
                }
            });`
```

Here is my PHP code

```
`include 'dbconnection.php';
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $keyword = $_GET['query'];

    //Build final SQL statement to search
    $selectsql = "SELECT MonAnID, MonAnName FROM ListMonAn WHERE MonAnName LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";
    //Display data to table
    $result = $conn->query($selectsql);

    $suggestions = array();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  

                $foodname = $row["MonAnName"];
                $foodid = $row["MonAnID"];  

                $suggestions[] = array(
                "value" => $foodname,
                "data" => $foodid
                );
            }       
    }

    echo json_encode(array(
        'query' => $keyword,
        'suggestions' => $suggestions));
    conn.close();`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms and this fixed it for me.

This is what I had before

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('#SelectedInput').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: '/AutoComplete/' + $('#SelectedInput').attr('data-autocomplete-action'),
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

This is what I had after

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, options) {
    var modalLoadUrl = '/MyController/GetModalContent';
    if (options.url == modalLoadUrl) {
        $('#SelectedInput').autocomplete({
            serviceUrl: '/AutoComplete/' + $(el).attr('data-autocomplete-action'),
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
});
```

Where I went wrong: I was loading the "SelectedInput" dynamically with and ajax call every time I opened a modal. Then I was setting up the autocomplete inside an ajax complete function. This, however, was also firing every time I was searching a query with autocomplete using ajax as well, which caused the search to reset every time I typed something new.

How I fixed it: All I needed to do was put the autocomplete method inside an if statement checking the requested url matched the url for the ajax call to load the page. Now the autocomplete method only runs once when the modal is loaded.